# Add private key to certificate or vice versa

Tags: ios, certificate, rsa, keychain

the problem is, that I want to create a new private/public key pair for a new App.

So i followed the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action) and it said  to first created a new key pair.

Ok, than i got a certificate signing request file, which i had to upload to the developer homepage (Certificate > Developement).
There I found out, that (and because) we allready have an app in the appstore, there is allready a certificate. So i downloaded the existing one and doubleclicked it in the finder. The keychain opended, but didn't append the certificate to the newly created private key (as i expacted).

What did I do wrong? What do i have to do, to activate this key pair?

Can someone help me in this issue?

Thanks
Br
Nic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Every certificate will have a public and private key. And also if you are talking about the developer certificate, every developer account can have only one certificate.

What you get to download from the apple website is only your public key. You need the private key to sign the apps. Your private key will be in the machine where you generated the CSR.

Check the "Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems" section in http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/howto.action to find out how to export your private key from that machine and use it in a different machine.

If you cannt get the machine where you generated the CSR, then you can revoke the existing one and generate a new one. But remember that this will make the existing profiles generated from this certificate invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I had to delete all my provisioning profiles and existing certificates and then I followed the step-by-step instructions from this article:

[Creating Your Signing Certificates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/CodeSigningYourApps/CodeSigningYourApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH23-SW1) by Apple and it had me up and running in 5 minutes after hours of banging my head!

Comment: "Creating Your Signing Certificates" is deprecated. Use this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html