# problem while configuring with IOS provisioning portal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, keychain

I am trying to configure with IOS provisioning portal. I am working on snow leopard machine and the problem is that when I download and install **WWDR intermediate certificate** it does nothing and do not create certificate in keychain.

when I click on WWDR Certificate it shows me this popup (Pic 1) and when I enter password It does not create certificate in keychain. As it is suppose to create like Pic 3 but it show like Pic2. I do not know where is the problem.

[image]

**Pic 1**

[image]

**Pic2**

[image]

**Pic3**

Comment: [This link ][1] could be useful to you.... Try to follow those steps....


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401088/key-chain-warning-the-system-roots-keychain-cannot-be-modified/5401379#5401379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WWDR intermediate certificate is not your development certificate.  Instead it contains the needed information about Apple's certificate authority.  You will still need to create a CSR and then download your certificate from the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

Actaully Its Drag and drop , I was double clicking the CSR and it does nothing but to ask for authentication.

But the solution was to **drag and drop CSR to keychain**.

thanks A for Alpha

Answer (score 0):

You need to select "My Certificates" or "Certificates" in the lower left sidebar in the Keychain Access app.  Currently you are filtering on Keys.