# The “System Roots” keychain cannot be modified

Tags: cordova, ios4, osx-snow-leopard, keychain

I have created the certificate and drop to Keychain Access for testing the application in ios device.This worked fine ,but i have one problem ,i am export the certificate from keychain Access for phonegap application.Now the keychain Access showing a warning ("The “System Roots” keychain cannot be modified.") while i am dragging Development Push SSL Certificate to Keychain Access and the old Development Provisioning Profiles do not working now .The ios application with old Development Provisioning Profiles give an error "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"

How can avoid this issue?

if anybody know please help me.

Comment: Please check  this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401088/key-chain-warning-the-system-roots-keychain-cannot-be-modified

Comment: [Perfect Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401088/key-chain-warning-the-system-roots-keychain-cannot-be-modified/10477317#10477317)

Answer (score 7):

The following solution worked for me.

```
Step 1. First go to keychain

Step 2. Go to login and drag and drop the certificates over here.
```

That's it, it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to modify its trust settings. Try to add it into Local Items or System first. Make sure that you've unlocked the keychain by clicking on the padlock.

See also:

[key chain warning The “System Roots” keychain cannot be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401088/key-chain-warning-the-system-roots-keychain-cannot-be-modified)