# Certificate Signing Request in Mountain Lion OS

Tags: macos, certificate, osx-mountain-lion, keychain

I recently installed the Mountain Lion OS on my Mac at work, only out of necessity. I tried to connect my App created in Xcode 5 to my iPhone, and it wouldnt work. I got the error "The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains." I figured out how to create a new certificate, and went to do so. On the way, I realized I needed a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) to do so. Most resources I found on the web pointed to using Keychain Access to create a new one. The link below said exactly what to do

[How to obtain Certificate Signing Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126496/how-to-obtain-certificate-signing-request)

Unfortunately, my Keychain Access does not have the "Certificate Assistant" section that is described in the step-by-step. All that is shown is what is in the image link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwjII.jpg

Comment: Look under the "Keychain Access" menu at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should see the "Certificate Assistant" section if you click on the "Keychain Access" menu.

It looks like this:

[image: Certificate Assistant is found in a menu]

Comment: ah, great didnt know mac os changes it top most menu according to the application