# Visual Studio Tools for Cordova - RemoteBuild for iOS fails

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Does anyone have idea what this error in VS means:

```
1>  Check dependencies
1>  No signing certificate "iOS Development" found:  No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "xxxxxxxx" with a private key was found.
1>  Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
```

App runs fine in simulator but I can't deploy to phone. I have both development and distribution certificates on Developer pages and imported in Keychain. Also, provisioning profiles for *com.companyname.appname* are added and downloaded with Xcode 8.

Where this "iOS Development" signing certificate must me present? Are there any additional settings that need to be configured for RemoteBuild (I guess that is fine since I can deploy to Simulator). My Macbook Pro is running El Capitan.

Comment: please check your certificates has private keys in keychain access.

Comment: @AmitSrivastava - no "private key" group... Only public, Fingerprints, Issuer... No mention of Private Key. Now what?

Answer (score 2):

> Where this "iOS Development" signing certificate must me present? Are there any additional settings that need to be configured for RemoteBuild (I guess that is fine since I can deploy to Simulator).

I guess you downloaded an existing Certificate from the Developer Page directly, which won't generate a private key in your Mac.

So to solve the problem, you need to find the private Key that paired with this Certificate(usually in the original Mac that request this Certificate) and export the Certificate(.p12 file) to your current Mac computer. For details, please refer to [Export your iOS Certificate and Provisioning Profile](http://devcenter.bitrise.io/docs/provprofile-cert-export).

If you can't find the private key, you need to request a new Certificate, and the private key will be generated automatically in your Mac. For details of requesting a new Certificate please refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126496/how-to-obtain-certificate-signing-request).