# Stuck: Request a certificate from a certificate authority in Keychain Access on Mac

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, keychain

My Request a certificate from a certificate authority in Keychain Access on Mac is stacked as per the below screenshot it is taking too long to generate the certificate.

I filled the email, name and email address of the certificate authority.

I may be wrong in filling
'email address of the certificate authority'

If so, what is the email address of the 'certificate authority'?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While "emailed to the CA" is the default radio button, are you requesting a codesign certificate from Apple?  If so, you need to change that radio button choice to save that request to disk, like this:

[image: like this]

And the details about what to do [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45504269/981049).

If you really do want to mail your certificate signing request to the certificate authority, you need to reach out to whoever your certificate authority is and get a valid e-mail address to send the Cert Signing Request.