# Apple provisioning no longer works with Visual Studio 2022 17.2

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I intend to download the renewed Apple developer certificates and provisioning profiles in Visual Studio 2022.

The new certificates and provisioning profiles are present in the Apple Developer website:

[image]

The keychain and Xcode contain the cert.

In the golden days, there was *Automatic provisioning* in Visual Studio.

***Apple decided to no longer support this.***

When I choose Automatic provisioning, I get an error, in the log, I have this message:

> The Apple Developer Portal web API for creating certificates is no longer supported. Please create your certificate manually

So I tried to create a manual cert in the Xamarin -> Apple Accounts pane, but it no longer contains a *Create certificate* or *Download all profiles* button.

[image]

If I download the .p12 file from the Mac and import it, it has no effect.

So what else can I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567877/stuck-request-a-certificate-from-a-certificate-authority-in-keychain-access-on

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved in version 17.3.1 of Visual Studio.

Visual Studio now uses an API key to access apple and create certificates, you'll have to delete the old account, create and use the new API key.

[Creating API Keys for App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api)