# How to create APNs as a team member

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, app-store, apn

I am a developer of a team and my account is not the holder on the developer.apple.com ( but it is admin)
our previous APNs was expired and I wanna create a new one, as you know when we want to create a CSR on the developer portal we need to have a `.certSigningRequest` file and we can generate it from opening `Keychain Access` application and open `Keychain Access` -> `Certificate Assistant` -> `Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority` from menu, in the window we have some textfields and one of the called `User email address`

so here is my question: which email should I put in the box? should I put my email or the account holder's email?

[image]

Comment: Enter your user email address and common name. Use the same address and name as you used to register in the iOS Developer Program. No CA Email Address is required.


[How to obtain Certificate Signing Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126496/how-to-obtain-certificate-signing-request)

Comment: @RsD which name and email I must enter?my email or the account holder's email? As I wrote I am not the account holder and I don’t log in with account holder information, I log in with my account and my account role is admin.

Comment: yes you can enter the admin email address and admin name.