# How to Installing Apple push Notification service certificate in Keychain?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, keychain

> "The “System Roots” keychain cannot be modified. To change whether a
>   root certificate is trusted, open it in Keychain Access and modify its
>   Trust Settings. New root certificates should be added to the login
>   keychain for the current user, or to the System keychain if they are
>   to be shared by all users of this machine."

It is showing above warning when I am trying to install the certificate.

How to solve this issue? Need urgent response.

Comment: You haven't find solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401088/key-chain-warning-the-system-roots-keychain-cannot-be-modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember, you should install certificate to `login` keychain.