# System Roots keychain cannot be modified in keychain

Tags: xcode, system, keychain

> To change whether a root certificate is trusted, open it in Keychain Access and modify its Trust Settings. New root certificates should be added to the login keychain for the current user, or to the System keychain if they are to be shared by all users of this machine.

I have tried removing all certificates and adding them again, but I am still getting this error. I also tried dragging and dropping the certificate on the "Certificates" section, and it added successfully, but it was not displayed in Xcode

I also tried [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401088/key-chain-warning-the-system-roots-keychain-cannot-be-modified)